# Searching objects in sys.objects I noticed that my table types have a prefix and suffix for name column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I run following query for recent changes in a database, I noticed that my table types come with a prefix and suffix.

Why is that so for table types?

```
SELECT type, type_desc, name, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
ORDER BY create_date desc
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User defined table types should primarily be thought of as types. This means that when trying to locate metadata about them, your starting point should be `sys.types` (or `sys.table_types`, specifically), where you will find the objects named without prefix or suffix.

Further, when wanting to explore the schema of a table type, one should be using `type_table_object_id` from `sys.table_types` to find the appropriate `sys.object`, rather than trying to locate them by name.

Within `sys.objects`, we can note two important things - these objects are in fact part of the `sys` schema, and are marked as `is_ms_shipped`. These objects, specifically, are considered to be system objects. That they all exist within the `sys` schema but need unique names points to one reason for needing suffixes. That they also share the `sys` schema with other system objects points to a reason for needing a prefix.

So I'd say the `TT_` prefix is to avoid naming collisions with other object types within the `sys` schema, and the `_47DBAE45` suffix is to avoid conflicts between multiple table types where the *types themselves* have the same names but exist in different schemas.

---

Having created two `Students` table types, one in `dbo` (as shown in the question) and one in `Xyz`, I run the following query:

```
select SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id), tt.name,
       SCHEMA_NAME(so.schema_id),so.name,
      so.is_ms_shipped
from sys.table_types tt
inner join sys.objects so
    on tt.type_table_object_id = so.object_id
```

Shows this result:

```
              name                  name                    is_ms_shipped
------------- ----------- --------- ----------------------- -------------
dbo           Students    sys       TT_Students_01142BA1    1
Xyz           Students    sys       TT_Students_02FC7413    1
```